# Generating a single lua bytecode file from multiple lua files for Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk, bytecode

I am developing a lua library for Corona which contains code spread across files. I am using luac to generate a single bytecode file which I can share with other developers so that they can use my library easily and without looking at code. Problem is that I am getting "bad header in precompiled chunk" error. From searching around, I find that its because I need to compile for ARM.

What would be right approach for me here?

Comment: Are You sure the same version of `luac` on build machine and `lua` on executing machine are running?

Comment: "...without looking at code". Do you want to do this to prevent reverse engineering? If this is the case, keep in mind that bytecode obfuscation is no way comparable to a strong encryption algorithm. A motivated user could reverse engineer your code with ease. A restrictive, proprietary license could serve you better to defend your copyrighted code. Of course this is worth the fuss only if your library is **really** competitive (both in features and quality) compared with all the (high quality) FLOSS Lua code in the wild (usually coming with a very liberal license as MIT/X11).

Comment: No reverse engineering is not so much of an issue. Essentially I want the output to be one lua file instead of 15 files so its easy to integrate for 3rd party developers

Answer (score 2):

Lua bytecode is not portable neither across version, nor across platforms; see [luac docs](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/luac.html).

**Update**

If you are just trying to pack some files together you could see [Squish](http://matthewwild.co.uk/projects/squish/home).

If you need a real deploying system for Lua there is [Luarocks](http://luarocks.org/).

Comment: LuaJIT bytecode [is portable](http://luajit.org/extensions.html#string_dump) across platforms.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks for pointing this out. Is corona based on LuaJIT or can it be used with LuaJIT?

Comment: Thanks, I will look in to LuaJIT and see if it works for my scenario.